# Unable to pass Button value from Child to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to create a very small react app that has a button with a latex-symbol which, when clicked, displays how one can include that symbol in latex.
I'm using an npm package ("react-katex") to render latex code on the browser.
The button renders fine, but when I click on the button, I don't get the desired result.

I've structured my app so that I have a parent component (App) which has a child component (Latex) which has the button. I thought of using the value attribute of the button tag to pass the value to the parent on an "onClick" event. That way, in the `onClick` event handler, I could use the `event.target.value` attribute to achieve my purpose. However, `event.target` doesn't even refer to the button when I run the program. Here's a snipped of code:

For the App component:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        symbolName: ''
    };
}

onButtonClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target)
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className='tc'>
            <Latex buttonClick={this.onButtonClick}/>
            <h1> {this.state.symbolName} </h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

for the Latex component:

```
const Latex = ({ buttonClick }) => {
    return (
        <div className='tc'>
            <button onClick={buttonClick} value={latexSymbols[0]}>
                <InlineMath>
                    {latexSymbols[0]}
                </InlineMath>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So, on clicking the button, instead of getting something along the lines of `<button value={latexSymbols[0]}>...</button>`, the output I get is `<span class="mrel amsrm">...</span>`. I'm assuming this is how the react-katex package renders the latex-symbol. But this is confusing me since the symbol wasn't the target of the event, the button was. Is there a work-around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

Instead of using `event.target` use `event.currentTarget`

```
onButtonClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
}
```

---

### Why?

**`event.target`** is the thing that is clicked on. Because you have a component *within* your button, it's going to be that, not the `button`.

**`event.currentTarget`** is the thing that actually has the `event listener` attached to it. In this case, `button`.

---

Answer (score 1):

`target` not always refers to the element that has the handler attached on (it refers to element that triggered the `click`). You should use `currentTarget` which represents the element that the event listener is attached to.

```
onButtonClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can do it like this***
buttonClick is a callback function if you need a value just pass button value instead of the event in a case when you will need button value and event together
`onClick={(event) => buttonClick(event, latexSymbols[0])}`  use something like this

`const Latex = ({ buttonClick }) =*emphasized text*> {
    return (
        <div className='tc'>
            <button onClick={() => buttonClick(latexSymbols[0])} value={latexSymbols[0]}>
                <InlineMath>
                    {latexSymbols[0]}
                </InlineMath>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}`